# Python validation error object is not json serializable

Tags: python, django

I have an exception which gives me error from form like::

```
except ValidationError as e:
    return JsonResponse(e, safe=False)
```

It is giveing me the error 
`ValidationError({'age': [u'This field is required.'], 'name': [u'This field is required.']}) is not JSON serializable`

Why I am getting this error and how can I make it work .. Any idea ??

Comment: If you're using a form then why not let the form handle the validation as normal? Please try to show a [mcve]

Comment: @Sayse I am posting the from form ajax so I want to send the error as response..

Comment: Don't know why you @ -ed me. But still, Sayse's point is still valid; the form collects the validation errors into an error list, and it's that that you should be serializing. Don't return responses from inside form methods, in any case.

Comment: Yes it is giving me validatation errors in list but it is not being serialized. How come ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `e` is an instance of `ValidationError`, not a `dict`. In order to access the message details you can use the [`.message_dict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/exceptions/#ValidationError) property:

```
return JsonResponse(e.message_dict, safe=False)
```

Comment: It is giving me error `dict object is not callable`

Comment: thanks man.. worked like a charm.. one question.. I have tried this too `# response = serializers.serialize('json', e)
   return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)` and why it didn't worked. It is supposed to serialize this right ?

Comment: Again, your `e` variable is not serializable. So no, this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json

as simple as:

```
except ValidationError as e:
  return e.as_json
```

Answer (score 0):

For me given answers didn't work. I've solved it by using `ValidationError` method `get_full_details()`.

```
except ValidationError as e:
    return JsonResponse(e.get_full_details(), safe=False)
```